# Swift - How to vertically transform (flip) a custom UITableViewRowAction

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, tableview, transform

I'm trying to implement the swipe to delete row actions in my table view, but for design purposes the table view is flipped upside down using `tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)` So my big red delete button is upside down. Is there an easy way to use     `cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)` on it?

I've tried to make my own swipe action using the following method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                 editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default,
                                      title: "Delete",
                                      handler: { (_: UITableViewRowAction, _: IndexPath) -> Void in

      })
    //Flip the text here
    return [delete]
  }
```

but all I see are background color and effect.

Any help? :) Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

could you manually flip the image you want to use and assign it like this?

```
let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { (_, _, completionHandler) in
    self.viewModel.deleteScan(at: indexPath.row)
    completionHandler(true)
}

deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "upside-down-delete")
deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Red800-Red500")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The only problem I'm having with this now is returning it in the function as it expects an array of [UITableViewRowAction], or did you mean use this somewhere outside that function?

Comment: I managed to get that working but only on with 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                 leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {}

unfortunately the opposite side i want